# in windows how to compile and run mercury program

Tags: mercury

I was able to download and unzip mercury file from http://dl.mercurylang.org/index.html . However, i could not figure out how to compile and run one of the programs .

I googled to find command '$ mmc calculator.m' to run mercury file but I am getting below error.

-bash: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/mmc: Permission denied

I am running command in cygwin.

Comment: Did you try the Windows binary package at the bottom of the download page? I've got zero experience dealing with Mercury on Windows, but I imagine that binary installer should work fine.

Comment: in windows i faced problem as the command mmc was in conflict with some  windows's other command.  However, when i try to install in linux . it worked fine.